# What scenarios to write a script to dynamically add a .current (active-like class) to an element?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

Working a navigation menu 'component' - looked at some examples of and many of them use controllers/javascript to dynamically add a *.current (active-like class)*. For example: https://www.google.com/analytics/ nav bar does this. Have always thought that the browser does that for you. I thought may be it was limited element wise but [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active) say  no.

> :active CSS pseudo-class  matches when an element is being activated by the user. It allows the page to give a feedback that the activation has been detected by the browser.  **It is frequently used on `<a>` and `<button>` HTML elements, but may not be limited to just those.**

Pseudoclass vs class: the one other distinction - is that it adds a pseudoclass vs a standard class. But not sure where the limitations on lie with depending just on the psuedo class.

Right now I have it working relying on the psuedo class and browser adding it. ie main-nav a:active, a:focus, etc but assuming something will want me to change/rework.

Comment: Please fix your quote from MDN. It should read **It is frequently used on `<a>` and `<button>` HTML elements, but may not be limited to just those.**

Comment: done thx - didn't use backtick escapes - to make them show

Comment: It might make it clearer if you didn't refer to it as an "active" class...but rather as `.current` to avoid confusion. `:active` only applies when the mouse button is *held down*.

Comment: Ah, so what you are saying is that you need both `:active` and `:focus` to highlight on the click and when to stay highlighted after mouse click. When you dynamically add a class like `.current` is that meant to handle both - i presume since it adds the class on the click - and removes it when another navlink is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

The quick answer is that browsers automatically make `<a>`, `<button>`, `<select>`, and `<input>` elements active when clicked but other elements like navigation tabs and menus need a controller or jQuery plugin to set those elements active when clicked. Navigation tabs, date pickers, menus, etc. all need controllers setting active class on selection.

Comment: So, it does have to do with limitations of elements that are affected by the browser. Is your basic rule thumb - that for any beyond the elements that you mention - you are already thinking a controller/script will be needed. Or, does scenario & framework play a large part as well? thx